# What are the grammatical terms to describe the way of using the adjective "beautiful" in these two sentences?

Tags: word-request, terminology

What are the grammatical terms to describe the two different ways of using the adjective "beautiful" in these two sentences?

1. The beautiful girl
2. The girl is beautiful

If I explain the concept of using the adjective in these two sentences, what are the grammatical terms or ways of explaining these two?
I want to explain this grammar point in another language, so I want to know a way to explain the difference between these two.

Comment: Have you researched this? Google "simple sentences".

Comment: Sorry if my question is not clear. I'm asking how to explain the adjective "beautiful" in these two sentences. I'll make this post more clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first sentence, the adjective is [attributive](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/attributive).

> (of the position or use of an adjective, noun, or phrase) before a noun:
> In "a sudden movement", "sudden" is an adjective in the attributive position.
> In "the television aerial", "television" is a noun used in an attributive way.

In the second sentence, it is [predicative](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/predicative).

> (in grammar, especially of adjectives or phrases) following a verb:
> In the sentence "She is happy", "happy" is a predicative adjective.